# Loading JSON object in Python using urllib.request and json modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having problems making the modules 'json' and 'urllib.request' work together in a simple Python script test. Using Python 3.5 and here is the code:

```
import json
import urllib.request

urlData = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Boras,SE"
webURL = urllib.request.urlopen(urlData)
print(webURL.read())
JSON_object = json.loads(webURL.read()) #this is the line that doesn't work
```

When running script through command line the error I am getting is "**TypeError:the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'**". I am new to Python so there is most likely a very easy solution to is. Appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Apart from forgetting to decode, you can only read the response *once*. Having called `.read()` already, the second call returns an empty string.

Call `.read()` just once, and *decode* the data to a string:

```
data = webURL.read()
print(data)
encoding = webURL.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')
JSON_object = json.loads(data.decode(encoding))
```

The [`response.info().get_content_charset()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_content_charset) tells you what characterset the server thinks is used.

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> import urllib.request
>>> urlData = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Boras,SE"
>>> webURL = urllib.request.urlopen(urlData)
>>> data = webURL.read()
>>> encoding = webURL.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')
>>> json.loads(data.decode(encoding))
{'coord': {'lat': 57.72, 'lon': 12.94}, 'visibility': 10000, 'name': 'Boras', 'main': {'pressure': 1021, 'humidity': 71, 'temp_min': 285.15, 'temp': 286.39, 'temp_max': 288.15}, 'id': 2720501, 'weather': [{'id': 802, 'description': 'scattered clouds', 'icon': '03d', 'main': 'Clouds'}], 'wind': {'speed': 5.1, 'deg': 260}, 'sys': {'type': 1, 'country': 'SE', 'sunrise': 1443243685, 'id': 5384, 'message': 0.0132, 'sunset': 1443286590}, 'dt': 1443257400, 'cod': 200, 'base': 'stations', 'clouds': {'all': 40}}
```

Answer (score 6):

As I study myself you just need to use `decode('utf-8')` function, then after use `json.load()` function to extract into json format.

```
>>> import json
>>> import urllib.request

>>> urlData = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Boras,SE"
>>> webURL = urllib.request.urlopen(urlData)
>>> data = webURL.read()
>>> JSON_object = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
{'coord': {'lat': 57.72, 'lon': 12.94}, 'visibility': 10000, 'name': 'Boras', 'main': {'pressure': 1021, 'humidity': 71, 'temp_min': 285.15, 'temp': 286.39, 'temp_max': 288.15}, 'id': 2720501, 'weather': [{'id': 802, 'description': 'scattered clouds', 'icon': '03d', 'main': 'Clouds'}], 'wind': {'speed': 5.1, 'deg': 260}, 'sys': {'type': 1, 'country': 'SE', 'sunrise': 1443243685, 'id': 5384, 'message': 0.0132, 'sunset': 1443286590}, 'dt': 1443257400, 'cod': 200, 'base': 'stations', 'clouds': {'all': 40}}
```

Answer (score -1):

with an evalstr:

```
   println('openurl: '+ 
   eng.EvalStr('json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen("'+
                           urlData+'").read().decode("utf-8"))'));
```