# send http request using django and get results

Tags: python, django, google-maps, http, reverse-geocoding

This might seem like an extremely simple and stupid question yet i can't find a convenient answer.
I'm trying to use google's reverse geocodding api with django, as the website explains (at `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1#ReverseGeocoding`) I'm supposed to send a request to the url :
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=<_api_key>`
But I can't find an appropriate way to send this request using django to google api.
To me it seems something so simple will be doable by some method built-in django but all I could find was modules to install.
If there's no way but installing other python modules which one's the best?

Comment: Try with http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, the most straightforward way would be to install [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library and simply call:

```
result = requests.get(your_link)
```

You can find additional information (e.g., how to authenticate, use cookies, etc., as well as how to access data in response) in the library's [docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). The `requests` library is very well written, very intuitive and simple to use. Quite a lot of smart people and companies use it, too, so it's not a half-baked library someone just hacked out over the weekend (as of this moment, it has 6060 commits and 595 contributors on [GitHub](https://github.com/psf/requests)).

If you absolutely must avoid external libraries, why not try [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request). It's a bit more complicated, and even the docs themselves recommend using `requests` if you prefer higher-level interface. But you definitely can get the job done with it. To get started, you can read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/howto/urllib2.html) on how to use it to fetch data. Read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795460/loading-json-object-in-python-using-urllib-request-and-json-modules) for an example of how to extract json from a response you'd get with `urllib`.