# How can i build a proper restful response API by python flask for parameters

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm studing about RESFful API with python.
I want to build a my restful api server,
but i have a problem,
i don't know how my api server returns proper data by reqeust each parameters

(request code sample)
the request code wants to get the information about 'item' : 'sword'

```
import requests
import json
url = "https://theURL"
querystring={"item":"sword"}
response = requests.request("GET", url, params=querystring)
print (response.json())
```

(API server response code sample, by flask python)

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, abort, reqparse
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

TODOS = {

    "version":"2.0",
    "resultCode":"OK",
    "output":{
         {
        "item" :"sword"
        "price": 300,
        "damage": 20,
         },
        {
        "item" :"gun"
        "price": 500,
        "damage": 30,
         },
        },
}

class Todo(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return TODOS

api.add_resource(Todo, '/item.price')


if __name__ == "__main__":
           app.run(debug=True, host ="192.168.0.8", port = 8080)
```

So i want to know how i use a code in response api server for returning 'item price' data by reqeusted parameters 'item : sword'
I just want to get the selected parameter's item price and damage information.

I thought it might be very easy, i'm tried to search the example but i couldn't find proper sample code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return JSON response from Flask view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081532/return-json-response-from-flask-view)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Flask-expert, but [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/) helps setting up and running a minimalistic Flask-server. Then, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081532/) explains how to return json-formatted data from your server, and finally how to request and interpret the json-response can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795460/). Summarized below:

Server returning a json-formatted data:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"


@app.route('/request_sword')
def grant_sword():
    return jsonify({"sword": {"name":"Excalibur","price":"stack overflow"}})
```

Client requesting json-formatted data:

```
import json
import urllib.request

url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/request_sword" ## My local host flask server

data  = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

response = json.loads(data.read())

print(response)
```

That's all really. You may also just enter the url in your browser, which will correctly read the json-data:
[image]

Comment: So, Should I classify all of items by each 'def' and path? (/'item name')

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question? I only provided a minimal example: you may extend the REST call `/request_sword` to take arguments, treat them and return a customized, complex json-data structure.. if that's what you want?

Comment: @HeartAimDJ : if the above solution helped you solve your problem, please mark the answer as accepted. If not, please add some more details to your question, explaining what is not working as expected.

Comment: I want to create a server that provides different data for each request, for example, request sword,  request gun. You wrote code about just one of item, sword